# What is causing the Java VM on OS X to crash with "Invalid memory access of location java"?

Tags: java, macos, memory, crash

The full message that I got on the console is:

```
Invalid memory access of location 00000000 eip=0117f7e1
Bus error
```

I don't remember seeing the Java VM crashing with this before, and I wasn't running code that was particularly new. Have you ever seen this before?

I got this error running Java 1.5 on OS X. The precise version is:

```
java version "1.5.0_19"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_19-b02-304)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_19-137, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the error every time under the same conditions even on different hardware?

Comment: I got this problem twice in the row, but haven't tried running this on a different machine. Trying on different hardware will be complicated as this requires a fairly sophisticated setup.

Comment: Are you using JNI, directly or via some library?

Comment: I should note that this has only happened when the VM was in debug mode (-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE). I didn't have this problem when those options were not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a NULL pointer dereference with address 00000000. You should report it to the JRE vendor.

Answer (score 1):

This is an access violation of the jvm, which is a bug. The version of the jvm you are using is already pretty dated. I'd recommend upgrading to a newer version of the jvm

Comment: As far as I know this is the latest 1.5 VM for OS X. I could be using 1.6, prefer to use 1.5 as our software needs to run on 1.5 as well.

Comment: Can you provide the call stack?

Comment: on mac os x 1.4, the latest version is 1.5

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error with

java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02-279-10M3065)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01-279, mixed mode)

I am on MacOSX 10.6.4

It happened when I tried to use the http://commons.apache.org/dormant/feedparser/ on a list of a few thousand rss feed urls which I tried to parse with multiple concurrent threads. 
I tried with 2, 5, 10 concurrent threads in a Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads)

but everytime I got this error. Now I am using just a single thread without the threadpool which is way slower but so far none of those errors. maybe it just happens later on the way, as of the lower throughput (because of single threading)....i will see...

Comment: My process is running now for about 14 hours and the error has not happened yet. So I claim it is related to multiple concurrent threads somehow.